# What is the easiest way to determine the accepted language of a deterministic finite automaton (DFA)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

I'm new to automata theory and I'm currently working on some exercises on determining the accepted language of DFAs. I was wondering whether there exists some clever strategy to determine the accepted language of a DFA. For example, I have the following DFA over the alphabet {0, 1}:

[image]

What is be the best approach to solve such problems?

Comment: You might get better answers to questions like these if you post on cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: But please don't re-post the same question on multiple sites, as that is forbidden by site rules.  You can always flag your question for migration if you think it is better elsewhere, but this question is likely already answered by the reference questions on CS.SE, so take a look at them first before requesting migration.

Comment: Ok, I had posted this question also on Stackoverflow, but it is deleted now. Thank you, it won't happen again :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the language of a finite automaton](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739863/finding-the-language-of-a-finite-automaton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start analyzing from the final state $q_2$:
$$
u(0|1)^*
$$
where $u$ is a prefix word. Arrival only via accepting a $1$ coming from $q_1$ or $q_0$:
$$
v1(0|1)^*
$$
where $v$ is another prefix word. Joining the start state $q_0$ via the upper (via $q_1$) or lower edge (direct):
$$
(00)^*(0|\epsilon)1(0|1)^*
$$
which simplifies to
$$
0^*1(0|1)^*
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I didn't know that it is possible to convert a DFA to it's regular expression. That helps a lot to determine the pattern of the accepted language by just looking at the regular expression. That was exactly what I was looking for. Is this a general approach? Can you do this with every DFA?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_nondeterministic_finite_automaton) and then at the link from @user2566092. It explains how to go from DFA to GNFA with several regexps as transition labels into collapsing to a GNFA with one combined regexp.

Comment: Dear downvoters: I have no clue what might be not useful or wrong, so I can't fix this answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very small DFA, so I’d use a fairly *ad hoc* approach. Notice first that its language is precisely the set of words that reach $q_2$: once it gets to $q_2$, it stays there, and there is no other acceptor state. Thus, we need only see what words get to $q_2$.

Clearly we need a $1$ at some point. It can come right away, thanks to the $q_0\overset{1}\longrightarrow q_2$ transition, or it can come after some $0$s. How many $0$s? One $0$ gets us to $q_1$, at which point a $1$ takes us to $q_2$. Two $0$s take us back to $q_0$, at which point a $1$ takes us to $q_2$. In fact, it appears that any number of $0$s (including none at all) followed by a $1$ will get us to $q_2$. Thus, anything conforming to the regular expression $0^*1$ gets us to $q_2$. After that we can have anything at all, so the language of the DFA must be $0^*1(0+1)^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Any path from the start state to an accept state is a string in your language, and if you find a loop from a state A back to itself then you can repeat the loop string as many times as you want after you reach A and then if you can reach an accept state from A then this will lead to an infinite family of accepted strings where the loop string is repeated some arbitrary number of times. Applying this kind of reasoning, you can often figure out the regular expression for a not-too-complicated DFA. If you want an algorithm that is guaranteed to work for any minimal DFA, see

http://regex-automaton.com/conversion_of_dfa_to_regular_expressions.php

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739863/finding-the-language-of-a-finite-automaton) will help you. You have to solve the system of equations under the monoid $(\Sigma, \circ, \epsilon)$ :

$$\begin{cases}
\Xi_0 = 0 \Xi_1 \cup 1 \Xi_2
\\ \Xi_1 = 0 \Xi_0  \cup 1 \Xi_2
\\ \Xi_2 = (0 \cup 1) \Xi_2 \cup \left\{\epsilon \right\}
\end{cases}$$

for $\Xi_0$.