# Finding the language of a finite automaton

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, finite-automata

Is there any formal and elegant way of finding the language of a finite automaton?

For example, It's trivial that the language accepted by the following diagram of the automaton $A$ is 
[image]

$L(A) =  (a \cup b)^* $

Since every input word over $\left\{a,b \right\}$ leads to the final(and only) state of the automaton.

How can we find the language accepted by an abstract automaton, with, for example, 20 states??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is an elegant way to compute this.

The process of finding the language accepted by an automaton $A = (Q,\Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$ involves solving a system of equations over the monoid $(\Sigma, \circ, \epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ denoting the empty word of the alphabet.

Denote as $\Xi_i$ the language recognized by the automaton $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_i, F)$ and $Q= \left\{q_0,..,q_n \right\}$. 
That is, create for each state of the initial automaton a new automaton with an initial state $q_i$, for $i=0,1,..,n$. Now denote $L_{ij}$ the language consisting of all the letters on the diagram of $A$ that start from $q_i$ and end at $q_j$. So from there there is the system

$$\Xi_i = \bigcup L_{ij} \Xi_j \cup Mi$$

where $M_i = \emptyset$ if state $i$ is not final, ${\epsilon}$ otherwise.

So to find the language of the automaton $A$ we got to solve the above system of equations and find $\Xi_0$ under the operations defined by the monoid.

To solve this system we can use the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $L.M \subset \Sigma^*$ languages. The smallest language satisfying the equation
$$Z = LZ \cup M$$ is $L^* M$.

For example consider the automaton:

$A = (\left\{q_0,q_1,q_2\right\},\left\{a,b \right\},\delta, q_0,\left\{q_2 \right\})$ with the state diagram of $\delta$ as follows

[image]

The system of equations is

$$\begin{cases}
 \Xi_0 = a \Xi_0 \cup b \Xi_1 
\\ \Xi_1 = b\Xi_0 \cup a \Xi_2 
\\ \Xi_2 = (a \cup b) \Xi_0 \cup \left\{\epsilon \right\}
\end{cases} $$

With substitution we obtain

$$\begin{cases}
 \Xi_0 = a \Xi_0 \cup b \Xi_1 
\\ \Xi_1 = b \Xi_0 \cup a ((a \cup b) \Xi_0 \cup \left\{\epsilon \right\})
\end{cases} $$

$$\begin{cases}
 \Xi_0 = a \Xi_0 \cup b \Xi_1 
\\ \Xi_1 = b \cup a ((a \cup b)) \Xi_0 \cup a)
\end{cases} $$

Substituting to the first equation we get

$$
 \Xi_0 = a \Xi_0 \cup b ((b \cup a ((a \cup b)) \Xi_0 \cup a) 
$$

$$
  \Xi_0 = a \cup (b^2 \cup b a^2 \cup b a b) \Xi_0 \cup ba
$$

Finally, applying our lemma

$$
  \Xi_0 = (a \cup b^2 \cup b a^2 \cup b a b)^* ba
$$

Thus the language accepted by the automaton is

$$L(A) = (a \cup b^2 \cup b a^2 \cup b a b)^* ba $$ as one can validate easily.